# Graph DB usable with Gremlin

Tags: graphs

We are exploring Gremlin language for our graph traversal requirements.

What graph database can I install, that will be traversable with Gremlin?

I must design my graph layer with Gremlin and keep it agnostic of the underlying Graph DB.

Comment: If you go with Neo4j, this plugin will help: https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/gremlin-plugin

Answer (score 0):

As I was reading further into the documentation of TinkerPop, I found that they support a variety of Graph DB systems under the hood. So I believe Gremlin would indeed support Neo4J if we were to switch to Neo4J or any other Graph DB under the hood.